# What part-of-speech will the new "because" be? because happy / sad / bored; because science /

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech, neologisms

The American Dialect Society [has voted *because* as the Word of the Year](http://www.americandialect.org/because-is-the-2013-word-of-the-year) owing to its increased use in phrases such as "because happy,"  "because sad," and "because bored."  Since it takes an object, it might be thought of as a preposition, but (as in the third example) it sometimes takes a participle or an adjective, can we really call it a preposition?  I need to know because curiosity.

Comment: A new part-of-speech?  Elliptoid?  Pro-eliption?

Comment: Why can't they just speak proper English?

Comment: Geoffrey Pullum has a comprehensive piece on it here: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494. ‘Contrary to all the dictionaries, it is a preposition.’

Comment: The new _because_ has an overlapping distribution with _being_ :'Because happy, gave $20 to charity' <==> 'Being happy, gave $20 to charity'. 'Being' in this type of construction also connotes at least partial causality. I realise this is contrary to the Pope's opinion. As MOS and WS2 imply, ellipses give rise to weird conclusions if the strange new usages have a classical analysis forced upon them. And there is often more than one possible analysis that **can** be forced upon them. –

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  All these new parts of speech must be good for the linguistics trade. We recently had an electrician round to see about having some new wiring done. 'Oh', said he with a sharp intake of breath, 'I hope you realise you are well short of current standards. I should have to do a lot of work here just to bring you in line.' The regulatory system, I've decided, is driven by sparkies to create more demand for the services of electricians. It's not like that in language development is it? Is it people like you and Barrie England who are behind all these new-fangled ways of speaking?

Comment: We're awfully quick to embrace memes and slang as permanent parts of English these days.

Comment: @WS2 "Why can't they just speak proper English?". Seriously? "Proper" English is the current usage, and this is a popular expression. How is that not proper?

Comment: See also my question here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119897/ending-a-sentence-with-because-noun for some other answers.

Comment: @George Stirling  Absolutely right George! I am glad we have some Mancunian common sense out there.

Comment: @ianjs So popular that I've never heard it. And what will happen next Monday when it goes out of fashion and half a dozen people start calling their insides their 'quibblies'. 'I've a pain in the quibblies'. Will you be petitioning for it to go in the OED?

Comment: I, too, had never knowingly heard it.  But, kinda like getting a new car, after I gave the matter the briefest consideration, I hear 'because #####' several times a day.

Comment: I notice from the OP that it is the 'American Dialect Society' which has honoured the word. So I'm glad to see that, whatever else, it only has dialect status, a bit like the way they say something is 'well good' in Manchester.

Comment: @WS2, Now I gotta ask what 'well good' means.  :)

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin In Manchester they will use 'well' in the kind of way that the rest of us use 'very'. 'My wife is well happy with our new house'. 'I was well pleased with the result'. I'm told it is spreading south and has reached Birmingham, so watch out! This business of using 'because' without an 'of' sounds as if it is another such affectation. We have already had to endure 'enjoy' as though it were an intransitive verb. I encourage the respect of old dialect forms, but creating new ones is ridiculous.

Comment: @ws2 You need to get out more; I see this usage all over the web. And as far as the OED is concerned, yes there will be a threshold beyond which they will feel obliged to include a new word because they recognise that languages are fluid and evolve over time.

Comment: @WS2 And then there’s the other *other* usage, where “because” no longer requires a stated reason ... *just because*.

Comment: What part of speech is it? May I suggest "a buggeration".

Comment: https://youtu.be/XFTnFhGuaBQ?t=28

Answer (score 8):

Because' has become a preposition, because grammar.

> The word "because," in standard English usage, is a subordinating conjunction, which means that it connects two parts of a sentence in which one (the subordinate) explains the other. In that capacity, "because" has two distinct forms. It can be followed either by a finite clause (I'm reading this because [I saw it on the web]) or by a prepositional phrase (I'm reading this because [of the web]). These two forms are, traditionally, the only ones to which "because" lends itself.

Read more:

http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/11/english-has-a-new-preposition-because-internet/281601/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't see any object in your examples. In any of these *because* is followed by an adjective: *happy*, *sad*, *bored*.

Furthermore, you should rather think of it being an ellipse as mentioned in comments.

> I don't go to the party, because (I am) tired. [*or* ...because of being tired]
>   I trust him, because (he is) honest.

Then, of course there are use cases where the verb being dropped is not *to be*; and *because* is indeed followed by something not being an adjective but by a noun. This noun may indeed be an object in a non-shortened version.

> I hate it because reasons.

You can consider this an ellipse of, for example:

> I hate it because of several reasons (...that I don't want to mention, *because too many*).
>   I hate it because there are many reasons that ...

So, *because* is actually used as *because of* and because of *because of* being a preposition, the 'new' *because* is also (and still) a preposition... because period.

Answer (score 0):

We know the preposition *"because"* can take a NP, a PP with 'of', or a clause as its complement.

> I won't go there because *I am tired*. (Clause as complement)

The part *"I am"* can be omitted. After ellipsis, we can say:

> I won't go there, *because tired*.

Therefore, **because** can be followed by an adjective, such as 'happy', 'sad', 'bored', 'tired' etc.

> I won't go there, *because tired*.
>
> Here, it is understood as *"because I am tired"*.

Comment: You state this as a static fact when it is a dynamic situation. 'Because of _NOUN_' is a well-established idiom. 'Because _NOUN_' is a very new phenomenon and is very much still non-standard. It sounds very slangy and would not be allowed by editors in formal speech or writing (news broadcasts or newspapers). As of 2022, it has not caught on more than rare bon mot.

Answer (score -1):

In homage to the aphoristic spirit of the American Midwest:

> Because needs fixed.

(you may take that either way.)