# Is "because-noun" a new preposition?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, dialects, language-evolution, language-change

There are a handful of articles suggesting that a new preposition has appeared in the form of "because-noun":

- [The Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/11/english-has-a-new-preposition-because-internet/281601/)
- [Stan Carey](http://stancarey.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/because-has-become-a-preposition-because-grammar/)
- [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-as-a-preposition)

Isn't "Because (of)... whatever" a causitive? Causitives are adverbs; in fact they are at very core of "adverbiality." That *happened* and now this *is* the result. The only way pre- and post-conditions arise is through a change (read: action) in condition or state. (Temporal consituents are more associated with adverbs, as well.) Prepositional phrases can ornament verbs, but not be inherent to them.

"I *am* an astronaut because science." = "Science is what *made* me an astronaut." There is no prepositional context here.

So I submit that there is actually no new "because-noun" grammatical form in American English, only a mildly-interesting economical shortening, like "Nope, he dead."

Comment: You might be interested in the Language Log posts ["Because syntax"](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494) and ["The promiscuity of prepositions"](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9558)

Comment: After read these links from the article I continued on, and the LL post I really enjoyed was http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9569. It's an interesting read. From the article: "In the case of because, the source is the **adverbial use of the prepositional phrase** "by cause":

1356   Wyclif Last Age Ch. (1840) 31   Þe synnes bi cause of whiche suche persecucioun schal be in Goddis Chirche.
1470–85   Malory Morte d'Arthur (1817) II. 452   By cause of brekynge of myn avowe, I pray yow all lede me thyder.

Comment: I don't particularly think that it is being used as a true preposition.  Yes, it is serving that purpose *grammatically*, but I have only seen such phrases as *because science* or *because reasons* being used facetiously.  Usually the author is deliberately playing at stupidity.  Whenever it is used, it is recognized as being incorrect.

Comment: You still don't see the logic? Because.

Comment: There's a whole lot of talk going on the Web bashing the *because <noun>* syndrome. It thrives, regardless.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a peeve.

Comment: Your astronaut example/explanation isn't completely accurate. Half of the point of "because X" is that it can also mean, "I am an astronaut *for* the science." Another example: "I came to the meeting because donuts." This gets comingled with your explanation but the double meaning is part of its charm.

Comment: By the way, I just performed a rather drastic edit to your question. If you object for any reason please roll it back. I attempted to make it a little less aggressive in hopes of getting a solid answer since I think this is a fancinating question.

Comment: It's a common phrasing on the internet. Why did they shut down that website. Because reasons. It probably started as a way of being cute and got out of hand.

Comment: Great edit, @MrHen!

Comment: Related: *[What part-of-speech will the new “because” be?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144778/)* and *[Ending a sentence with “because {noun}.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119897)*

Comment: Somehow I feel like it originated from "because pickles" in that one episode of Spongebob (titled *Pickles*, appropriately enough). Maybe that's just an urban myth, however.

Comment: What part of speech is 'I can haz cheezburgers' going to be?  Lordy Lord.  Comic turns of phrase have been around since forever, and we don't write them into the textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that David M's Comments explanation ("It probably started as a way of being cute and got out of hand.") is exactly on point. If someone writes

> Because donuts.

the phrase amounts to an extreme telescoping of a longer (usually jocular) idea along the lines of

> Because donuts are a consideration here—and when donuts are involved, nothing more need be said. I mean, think about it: *donuts*, for gosh sakes. OMG let's stop talking and get some donuts! Mmmmm, donuts!

This telegraphic style—with its omission of one, several, or many surrounding words—may or may not be linked to Twitter tweeting, but I don't see any necessary connection between the two. The first time I can recall encountering a similar wording involves Patti Smith's 1978 song "Because the Night"; in the full lyrics, the relevant wording turns out to be

> Because the night belongs to lovers. Because the night belongs to lust.

etc.; but the title itself was startling and provocative because it stopped at "Because the Night."

Antecedents aside, I don't think there's much point in trying to assign a part-of-speech identity to *because* in a "Because noun" formulation, since that formulation reduces the underlying idea to a vestigial remnant.

Comment: This is a fairly good explanation of the phenomenon.  But, it was popularized by Twitter.  So, it is indelibly linked to it.  The truncation may not be exactly due to the character restrictions, but I was making the point that truncation is commonplace when using the service.  I will edit to clarify that point.

Answer (score 0):

In modern grammar, 'because' is a preposition.

As its complement, it can take :

> 1. a clause :

I am an astronaut because *science has made me so*.

> 2. a prepositional phrase with 'of' as its head :

I am an astronaut because *of science*.

> 3. a noun phrase :

I am an astronaut because *science*.

(This usage is new.)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for logic where none exists. This is Twitter speak.

You have a few sources listed above to which I'll add [this](http://allthingslinguistic.com/post/67507311833/where-because-noun-probably-came-from) and [this](http://allthingslinguistic.com/post/26522214342/because-reasons).

Twitter limits you to 140 characters, so truncation has become quite popular.  And, as a natural side effect of Twitter and other services like it, language is evolving (*i.e.* being taken out back and beaten into a bloody pulp until it agrees to say what you tell it to…)

One of the more popular versions of this type of construct is *because reasons*.  As I stated in comments above, this was likely an attempt at humor that caught fire.  It was likely born of the brevity that character limits engender, and because of its inherent ironic humor, it rapidly gained in popularity.

I would posit that the internet is actually generating regional dialects all its own.  Much as terms from texting like LOL and OMG have broken into public consciousness, these are too.

Additionally, these constructs remind me of the regional dialects of areas like Pittsburgh. Where helper verbs and articles are often truncated. Instead of *I need a haircut* one might hear *I need haircut.*

In any case, I don't think the coiners are intentionally using it as a prepositional phrase. I think they are using it *because Twitter*!

Comment: So... is it a prepositional phrase?

Comment: @MrHen I supposed you could make the argument that it is.  But, I would submit that is like asking:  Are my 5 year-olds' (I have twins) drawings derivative of DaVinci (*e.g.* because of the quizzical smiles)?  I think that just because something appears to accidentally have become a de novo grammatical form, doesn't make it so.